# Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to place bottom image slightly above the top image. But after adding an offset to the anchor I get this error:

```
qrc:/Template.qml:21:22: Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine
```

after adding an offset of 20 pixels on this line:

```
anchors.top: top_bg.bottom-20
```

**How can I offset an item, using anchor as a reference point?**

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3

Item {
    id: root
    Image {
        id: top_bg
        source: "qrc:/images/top_bg.png"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: root.height*0.33
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
    }
    Image {
        id: map_bg
        source: "qrc:/images/map_bg.png"
        anchors.top: top_bg.bottom-20
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop

    }
}
```

Comment: You get error just because `anchors.bottom` is not a number but `AnchorLine`, in fact it is some type of enumeration so you cannot do the math on this. But you can use margins instead. So, in your case it should be `anchors.top: top_bg.bottom; anchors.topMargin: 20`. Read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html) article to get more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anchors are not numerical positions but positions relative to an item, they can not be added or subtracted, in your case you should use the properties `y` and `height`:

```
Image {
    id: map_bg
    source: "qrc:/images/map_bg.png"
    y: top_bg.y + top_bg.height - 20 // <---
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
}
```

Another option is to use the margins:

```
Image {
    id: map_bg
    source: "qrc:/images/map_bg.png"
    anchors.top: top_bg.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: -20
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
}
```

Comment: the problem is, using `y` and `x` is not good for scalable Qt applications that have to run on any resolution, including 4K mobile phones. here is what QT Scalability notes say on using `x` and `y`: "Do not have bindings to the x, y, width, or height properties of items in a Layout, since this would conflict with the goal of the Layout, and also cause binding loops." . Since I am building a reusable scalable component , it may be included in a layout.

Comment: @Nulik I have reviewed what it says but those recommendations have a context, the use of Qt Quick Layouts, not a direct link: ***Laying Out Screen Controls Dynamically*** *...Here are some things not to do with layouts:* *-Do not have bindings to the x, y, width, or height properties of items in a Layout, since this would conflict with the goal of the Layout, and also cause binding loops.*

Comment: @Nulik [cont.] and clearly the problem is the infinite loop that can be caused because there would be a double dependence, the layouts use the sizes of the items to establish positions, and with the properties x, y, width, height you would be doing the same possibly entering a loop .

Comment: @Nulik so the first option is correct if the Qt Quick Layouts are not used, also in my updated response I have added a second solution using margins